# Corona SDK offset not good

Tags: android, iphone, windows, lua, coronasdk

I just started using Corona SDK. And learning how to make apps with it. For example i am using:

```
local myRectangle = display.newRect( 0, 0, 150, 50 )
myRectangle.strokeWidth = 3
myRectangle:setFillColor( 0.7 )
myRectangle:setStrokeColor( 1, 0, 0 )
```

When i use this it will look like this on my phone

[image]

When i am using this code:

```
local myRectangle = display.newRect( 77, 27, 150, 50 )
myRectangle.strokeWidth = 3
myRectangle:setFillColor( 0.7 )
myRectangle:setStrokeColor( 1, 0, 0 )
```

Then it will looks like this on my phone:

[image]

It looks like the offset is not good. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At default, anchor point is in center of object. So if you set

```
myRectangle.x = 0 
myRectangle.y = 0
```

center of the object will be at 0, 0. To change it, set anchors to 0, 0 (top left)

```
myRectangle.anchorX = 0
myRectangle.anchorY = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I make objects, I always set the x and y to 0 in the actual API.  Then I do this after I create my object:

```
myRectangle.x = display.contentWidth/2
myRectangle.y = display.contentHeight/2
```

Hopefully this helps.